# Mask out specific pixels from a UIView based on where subviews are located

Tags: ios, uiview, quartz-graphics, cgcontext, quartz-2d

Say I have a main UIView which has several subviews of type CatView and DogView. I want to render this UIView as an image, but I want to exclude DogViews, so that the final rendered image has transparent pixels in place of any DogView. (Note that simply removing the DogViews from the view wouldn't work - I need transparent pixels where the DogViews were). Also the DogViews can be rotated so they don't necessarily take up rectangular portions of the view.

Any ideas on how I can approach this?

EDIT: First attempt

```
- (UIImage *)createCutOutViewFromView:(UIView*)view {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 200, 200);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 250, 200);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 250, 250);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 200, 250);
    CGContextClosePath(context);

    CGContextClip(context);

    [view.layer renderInContext:context];

    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return result;

}
```

The result is that I can only see the 50px rectangle that I clipped. I actually want to see everything EXCEPT this rectangle. Any advice?

EDIT: 2nd attempt

```
- (UIImage *)createCutOutViewFromView:(UIView*)view {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClearRect(context, view.bounds);

    [view.layer renderInContext:context];

    UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 200)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(250, 200)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(250, 250)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 250)];
    [path closePath];

    [path fillWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.0];


    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    return result;

}
```

Comment: Ah, that's the winding rule. Try drawing counter-clockwise.

Comment: Hmm. Still get just the small rect if I draw counter-clockwise.

Comment: That's weird. I was looking for an explanation of the winding rule, and I think I came up with an easier solution.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: See Edit 2. Nothing gets cut out now. Is there a certain blend mode I have to use?

Comment: Try kCGBlendModeClear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a bitmapped graphics context and render the view into that context.  Then for each DogView, create a UIBezierPath, and use `moveToPoint`, `addLineToPoint`, and `closePath` to draw an outline where the DogView would be.  Then call `fillWithBlendMode:alpha:` with an alpha of 0.0 to clear that region of the drawing.

I like to use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` to create the bitmapped graphics context since it only needs a size, which you can get from the view's bounds.  Here's the general framework.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( view.bounds.size );
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// drawing stuff goes here

UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: This sounds like great advice. I will give it a shot and post code here if I can't get it to work.

Comment: Do I use CGBitmapContextCreate? What are the correct parameters to start with?

Comment: @soleil I've updated the answer to give you a little head start.